# create dynamic link from Mysql table

Tags: php, dynamic-linking

Im trying to create dynamic links from some post inside a database table, 
but i cant figure out how to create the link, when the user is already logged in.

I think something like this.

```
    <?php $articles = new Articles();

foreach($articles->fetch_user_article($_GET['uid']) as $article) :?>
 <a href="edit_articles.php?uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']?>&article=<?php echo $article['id'];?>"><?php echo $article['title'];?></a>

    <?php endforeach ?>
```

This gives me a link that looks like this

```
edit_articles.php?uid=5&article=213
```

The article id:s are correct from the DB table.

Now my edit_articles.php file

```
$articles = new Articles();
$article = $articles->fetch_user_article($_GET['uid']); 
echo $article['text'];
```

But when im reach the edit_articles.php file i get

```
Undefined index: text
```

And my function

```
function fetch_user_article($uid){
        $uid = (int)$uid;
        $query = $this->link->query ("SELECT id, title,text FROM blog WHERE user_id = '{$uid}' ");
        $tweet = array();
        while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) { 
            $tweet[] = $row;
        }
        return $tweet;
    }
```

Comment: That's because there is no "text" index of the array article. Is article returned as an array from fetch_user_article()? or is it the actual article text. I would need to see the code for fetch_user_article() to help further.

Comment: @mlewis54 I updated the question with the function.

Comment: I believe that the array structure should be: $article[0]=>(id=5,title='blah',text='blah de blah blah"), $article[1]=>(id=5,'title 2',text='text 2') It appears that you need to refer to article[0]['text']. Use print_r($article) to see the array structure.

Comment: @mlewis54 yes im sure, if i add echo $article['text']; to my foreach loop its printing out all the articles. but not when im want a singel one in the edit_articles.php file.

Comment: Sorry, changed the edit and accidentally hit the return key.

Comment: @mlewis54 its driving me nuts :)
I did the print_r and it prints out like this 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 213 [title] => title1 [text] => blablabla ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 232 [title] => title2 [text] => blabla ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 273 [title] => title3 [text] => moreblabla ) )

So the text is there, but i cant see the uid=5 connected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function fetch_user_article is returning more than one article.
Use like this to fecth all articles.

```
$articles = $articles->fetch_user_article($_GET['uid']);

foreach ( $articles AS $article ) {
    echo $article['text'];
}
```

If you want fetch_user_article to return only one article, then the field user_id of table blog should be unique.

Or you will have to rewrite the query

```
 SELECT id, title,text FROM blog WHERE user_id = '{$uid}'
```

so it gives you only one result, something like:

```
      $article_id = $_GET['article'];
      SELECT id, title,text FROM blog WHERE id = '{$article_id}'
```

Comment: okej but how could i rewrite the query so it understand that when im want to enter post 270 it opens post 270 and not the first in the table ?

Comment: So the condition in you query should be WHERE id = 270.
Edited answer.

Comment: I tried as you said, just hardcoded the article_id in the function and it working like a charm. just need to send the article id now.
Thank you!!

Comment: You already have the article id in your code: 
edit_articles.php?uid=5&article=213 .

Use $_GET['article']

Comment: You was totally right. worked right of the box with your help.